# Excel VBA Loop on multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Hi im looking for some help on a loop i've been trying to work out. Its only for a football prediction spreadsheet.

Basically i have rows of peoples name where the guess the result and the score.

then i have the first 2 rows as the actual result and score.

I've created a function to calculate it but i need to loop through each row in ranges to add up the totals.

```
 `ResultRange = Range("B2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 ScoreRange = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 GuessResRange = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 GuessScoreRange = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Range("B14").Value = ScorePoints(InResultRows, InScoreRows,      InGuessResult, InGuessScore)
```

This is what I have so far.

Basically for 10 games ResultRows, ScoreRows, GuessResult, GuessScore

would go from B2,C2,D2,E2 to B3,C3,D3,E3 and so on until it hits the end of the scores. Then the total would be tallied up in Range B14. Then continuing this onto the next player?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to condense four Columns into only one Cell. But you can iterate over rows via `for each cell in Rangeobject.Rows.Cells`, where Rangeobject should be you four columns in one object.

Answer (score 0):

Still a bit unclear about what you're trying to do, but this might get you started:

```
Sub FootballPredict()

    Dim GuessResRange As Range
    Dim rngLoop As Range
    Dim dblSum As Double

    Set GuessResRange = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

'    For Each rngLoop In GuessResRange
'        'could use this loop to do something
'    Next rngLoop

    dblSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(GuessResRange)
    Range("B14").Value = dblSum

End Sub
```